# Counting element in occurrence counting

Tags: perl

Here I got a text file contains some subject results.
What is the possible way to do a counting table as below in Perl?

#### result.txt

```
Math Peter pass
English Peter pass
Music Peter fail
Science Peter fail
Art Mary fail
Music Mary fail
English Mary fail
Math Bob pass
English Bob fail
Art Bob pass
Music Bob fail
English Mike pass
Science Mike pass
```

#### Output

```
name    pass    fail
Peter   2   2
Mary    0   3
Bob 2   2
Mike    2   0
```

I have already tried this and can successfully print a dump in spited form

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

use Data::Dumper;

my $CurrentPath = "/tmp";

open(FILE, "/tmp/result.txt") or die("Cannot open file result.txt for reading: $!");
my @results = <FILE>;
s{^\s+|\s+$}{}g foreach @results;
close FILE;

my @data_split = ();

foreach my $result ( @results ) {
    push @data_split, [ split /\s+/, $result ];
}

print Dumper \@data_split;

1;
```

#### output

```
$VAR1 = [
          [
            'Math',
            'Peter',
            'pass'
          ],
          [
            'Eng',
            'Peter',
            'pass'
          ],
          ...............
```

Comment: Some [useful reading](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html#HASHES-OF-HASHES).

Comment: Your entire code can be written as `my @data_split = map [ split ], <FILE>`

Answer (score 2):

To count and manage a range of items, and for any structured information, hashes are very useful. With them and arrays you can via references build data structures that can encode rather complex relationships. See [perldsc](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html). Once these become unwieldy the next step is to write a class.

It can go along these lines

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';   
use Data::Dump qw(dd);

my $file = shift @ARGV;
die "Usage: $0 filename\n" if not $file;

open my $fh, '<', $file or die "Can't open $file: $!";

my %results;

while (<$fh>) {
    next if not /\S/;  # skip empty lines

    my ($subj, $name, $grade) = split;

    if (not $subj or not $name or not defined $grade) {
       warn "Incomplete data, line: $_";
       next;
    }

    if ($grade eq 'pass') {
        $results{$name}->{pass}++;
    }  
    elsif ($grade eq 'fail') {
        $results{$name}->{fail}++;
    }  
    else { 
        warn "Unknown grade format for $name in $subj: $grade";
        next;
    }
}
dd \%results;
```

Names without a single occurrence of a particular score stay without the hashref for that score. If you need those entries then post-process `%results` to add them, for example

```
foreach my $name (keys %results) {
    $results{$name}->{pass} = 0 if not exists $results{$name}->{pass};
    $results{$name}->{fail} = 0 if not exists $results{$name}->{fail};
}
```

Or, add a statement to initialize both scores for each record (name) in the code.

Note that we can enlarge this data structure to store more information (`$subj` for instance), as the need arises, cleanly and with small code changes. This is another benefit of using hashes.

A few comments on the posted code

- Why is there no `use warnings;` at the beginning? You must have that; it is *directly* useful
- Use lexical filehandles, `open my $fh, '<', $file ...` instead of globs (`FILE`)
- Process files a line at a time unless there is a *specific* reason to read the whole thing first
- You always want to check input against what you expect it to be; what exactly that is depends on your problem and designs. In the code above all fields must be defined and sensible (grade is allowed a 0), while you may in fact accept a non-existent grade; adjust as suitable.

  Of course, if *all files that this program will ever read* were like what you show, always with all fields and only pass/fail grade, then there would be no need to check input
- The pattern `/\s+/` in [split](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) should almost always be replaced with `' '`, which is the same but it also discards leading spaces. It is also the default, along with `$_` for the string, thus just `split;` above (the string it splits by `' '` is `$_`)
- You can built a data structure like the one used here with what you got as well. However I don't see a benefit of an array of arrays here

The increment of the appropriate counter can be written more concisely

```
while (<$fh>) {
    next if not /\S/;
    my ($subj, $name, $grade) = split;
    # check input ...

    if ($grade !~ /^(?:pass|fail)$/) {
        warn "Unknown grade format for $name in $subj: $grade";
        next;
    }   

    $results{$name}->{$grade}++;
}
```

If you'd rather have your code quietly accept *anything* at the third field and store it in `%results` with its count then remove the check against `pass|fail`.

Comment: @charlotte-saray In case you didn't see my previous comment, I added code to post-process the `%results` data structure (add fields with zero).  Please let me know if there are questions.

Answer (score -1):

This is a very basic solution that does no checking of the input data. It initialises each hash value to `{ pass => 0, fail => 0 }` so that there are no "missing" values that need to be defaulted

Note that Perl hashes are *unordered*, so the order of the output is also indeterminate. If you need anything specific then you must say so

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

open my $fh, '<', 'results.txt' or die $!;

my %grades;

while ( <$fh> ) {

    my ($class, $name, $grade) = split;

    $grades{$name} //= { pass => 0, fail => 0 };
    ++$grades{$name}{$grade}
}

say "name\tpass\tfail";

for ( keys %grades ) {
    say join "\t", $_, @{ $grades{$_} }{qw/ pass fail /};
}
```

#### output

```
name    pass    fail
Mary    0   3
Bob 2   2
Mike    2   0
Peter   2   2
```

Comment: This answer address merely the very question asked and ignores the many other issues in the question (opportunities to inform). I think that, "_given the triviality of the quesiton_" (in your own words), it is important to offer a wider guidance to writing robust programs.

Comment: @zdim: I will tolerate unreasoned votes, but if you have down-voted my answer because you think I down-voted yours then your behaviour is abysmal.

Comment: Um, no, and such a statement in public is a little offensive?  Since you ask: I downvote answers very, _very_ rarely (too much responsibility for me -- I would have to then keep track of whether they fix it to adjust the vote) and only when I consider it necessary as a way of informing the future readers.  Certainly not as a "revenge" or some such.

Comment: @zdim: *"This answer address merely the very question asked"* I consider that to be a compliment.

Comment: @zdim: *"such a statement in public is a little offensive"* So you see that discussing votes at all is counter-productive? I hope you will try to simply accept any contributions that are offered. *"Since you ask"* I didn't ask.

Comment: "_So you see that discussing votes at all is counter-productive?_" -- I know that so it surprised me when you brought it up.  I did thank you for advice of that kind (in the other thread) and removed my comment on voting.  Well, you did bring up voting and in a particular fashion. It is the contemplation of revenge downvoting that was "_a little offensive_" to me.

Comment: "_I consider that to be a compliment._"  -- well alright then. I firmly believe that we should let people know of issues in their posted code. To exaggerate, if they ask about the indicator while running the red light I think we should mention the traffic lights and not only answer the question.